# Why can't you change a property value permanently in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here's the code:

```
 class Person(var firstName: String, var lastName: String) {
    var fullName: String =  firstName + lastName
    
    fun fullName() = firstName + lastName

    override fun toString(): String {
        return fullName()
    }
}
fun main(){

    val test = Person("test", "fortest1")
   

    test.lastName = "fortest2"
    
    
    println(test.fullName)
}
```

The result will only be `testfortest1`.
It looks like you are working with a copy of `test` once `test` is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `fullName` is not observing any changes to `firstName` or `lastName`. It is initialized when `Person` is created and stays the same unless explicitly modified.
One easy fix for this is to provide a custom getter like this:

```kotlin
val fullName get() =  firstName + lastName
```

Now it will work as you expect because everytime you read `fullName` that expression will be evaluated and the result will be returned.

(Also, prefer using `val`s over `var`s in data class fields)